# MySQL adding extra backslashes?

Tags: mysql

```
@@SESSION.sql_mode;
@@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

both come up blank, the my.cnf shows no "NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPE" flag and this is a section of a query which runs on my local server but not on my main.

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `data` = "[{\"_talent\'s\"etc"
```

Now I know I can use "[{""_talents""etc" but I'd rather not since it is much easier for me to keep to my current escaping security methods which have always worked before.

The charset is UTF-8 of the table I'm updating. The strangest thing is that it works on insert but not update!

This one really has me scratching. Any ideas?

Cheers

edit:

I've found out that the server is trying to interpret the query like so:

```
Failed to execute SQL : SQL UPDATE `build` SET `data` = "[{\"_talent\'s" WHERE `build_id` = 1 AND `userId` = 1128; failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `build` SET `data` = "[{\\"_talent\\'s" WHERE `build_id` = 1 AND `userId`' at line 1
```

Yet surely it should be the same, why is the SQL engine escaping my escapes!? (if I leave out the escapes the query still fails)

Comment: **Blackslash**... is that some combination of Black Sabbath and Guns N' Roses? Please excuse the pun. Couldn't help myself.

Comment: please can someone help, I'm going out of my mind. It works on my local server, but not on the webserver. The webserver seems to be double escaping the same statement !! :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it seems to have been my version of webmin adding it in on the console... d'oh

When I ran the query from PHP it went through perfectly.

Many thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
UPDATE 'table' 
SET 'data' = '[{"_talents"etc'
```

Comment: Your edit does work but if I then change the string to talent's it fails again

Comment: @Dorjan - Try this, if you use single quote instead of double

Comment: I have done, which does work until I need to have a 's, this one feels totally illogical but I'm sure there is a sane reason why this isn't working :S Is it anything to do with utf8_general_ci or InnoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Is this relevant?

[MySQL / PHP problem with " and '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865086/mysql-php-problem-with-and)

Which implys you may have magic Quotes enabled somewhere to add extra backslashes (which may explain why you get odd behaviout on your server but not your local machine)?

The different behaviour on both platforms implies some configuration issue on the server to me (you sure they are the same version?) I'm reaching a bit here though.

Comment: The second part of my answer was more relevant though. :)